# How to access JSON data in $http.get method's response?

Tags: json, angularjs

JSON data is in following formate. I want to access it into `$http.get` method.  but getting something like not defined.

**Angularjs**

```
 $http.get("http://192.168.206.133:8080/admin/metering/project/")
    .success(function(response) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response.instances));
      //$scope.groups = response.instances[0];
      //$scope.group_by = $scope.groups[0];
    });
```

**JSON DATA**

```
[
    {
        "instances": [
            {
                "Name": "test2",
                "Id": "7a3a2eab-7d3b-498b-bc69-ba39396ada4f"
            },
            {
                "Name": "test1",
                "Id": "1114cb76-f3df-4c60-8b12-5ad14224ffbd"
            },
            {
                "Name": "ce-2",
                "Id": "8b97b82b-a9e4-4fe0-adcb-eeaaac170301"
            },
            {
                "Name": "ce-1",
                "Id": "afaa50ad-8025-415b-81c4-566c8e06f388"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following snipet

```
$http.get("http://192.168.206.133:8080/admin/metering/project/")
    .success(function(response) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response[0].instances));
      //$scope.groups = response.instances[0];
      //$scope.group_by = $scope.groups[0];
    });
```

Comment: sorry nothing happing, why you are using `data`. This is not any where in JSON data response

Comment: This `alert(JSON.stringify(response[0].instances));` is correct

Comment: He used response.data.property because the original XmlHttpRequest in JavaScript is sending the whole response object back, which contains a field data containing the requested data. The $http wraps this mechanism and strips the data from the response before it sends it back.

Comment: I used to do the same... :)

Comment: @NeelabhSingh but why using json stringify method? you can achieve it by   
below method

Comment: @TheMechanic if you window alert an object you'll find yourself reading [Object object] , with the Stringify method you will able to read a printed string version of your object in the alert.

Comment: @skubski you can always use console :)

Comment: @skubski you are right. breakpoint and debugging is always a good option but console is better than alert

Answer (score 0):

Try this in jquery format

```
var data = [
{
    "instances": [
        {
            "Name": "test2",
            "Id": "7a3a2eab-7d3b-498b-bc69-ba39396ada4f"
        },
        {
            "Name": "test1",
            "Id": "1114cb76-f3df-4c60-8b12-5ad14224ffbd"
        },
        {
            "Name": "ce-2",
            "Id": "8b97b82b-a9e4-4fe0-adcb-eeaaac170301"
        },
        {
            "Name": "ce-1",
            "Id": "afaa50ad-8025-415b-81c4-566c8e06f388"
        }
    ]
}]

var groups = data[0].instances;
for (i=0; i < groups.length; i++){
console.log(JSON.stringify(groups[i]));}
```

Check this angularjs [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/puboa651/) for angularjs way

Comment: This is just a copy from the other answer? Care to add anything ?:o

Comment: nope its not copy as you can see a little difference of "[]" array braces

Comment: There was no added value in your original answer nor was it correct for that matter.

Comment: @skubski  please check my fiddle and let me know

Comment: I'm not sure if that was the purpose. The original idea was to make a request to an external resource while you are using a global variable. Your fiddle works but I don't think that it is what he was trying to archieve. On a sidenote you should take a look into the controllerAs syntax AngularJS provides since 1.3.x (Not really sure) so you can get rid of $scope and use namespacing instead. @TheMechanic